# How to InputClickEvent with MRTK v2 C#

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk

I had `HoloToolkit-Unity-2017.4.3.0-Refresh` in my project but some in the built in scripts has gone obsolete. I worked around this and recently added an `OnInputClicked` method but when trying to build this there were so many error in other scripts that I changed to MRTK v2.

I looked around a bit but couldn't seem to find any tutorials on how to make a click event for HoloLens device in any of MRTK v2s documentation. `IInputHandler` is no longer in the MRTK, but does `IMixedRealityInputHandler` work the same?

The code below is how the clickEvent used to look like with the `HoloToolkit`. Is it still the same with MRTK v2?

```
public void OnInputClicked(InputEventData eventData)
{ 
   ...
}
```

Also is this sufficient enough to trigger other methods or do I have to add the click event in the `void Update()`-ish? Another also - is this enough for triggering a click event through the hololens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I looked into it and apprently it changed (?) to

```c#
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour, IMixedRealityInputHandler
{
    public void OnInputUp(InputEventData eventData)
    {

    }

    public void OnInputDown(InputEventData eventData)
    {

    }
}
```

Or maybe you rather want the `IMixedRealityPointerHandler`

```c#
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour, IMixedRealityPointerHandler
{
    public void OnPointerUp(MixedRealityPointerEventData eventData)
    {

    }

    public void OnPointerDown(MixedRealityPointerEventData eventData)
    {

    }

    public void OnPointerClicked(MixedRealityPointerEventData eventData)
    {

    }
}
```

and than yes that should afaik be enough to get those methods called (ofcourse it also needs a Collider somewhere on the GameObject or its children).

[Here](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Input/Overview.html) you can find a complete overview over what Input is available in MRTK 2 and how to set it up.

Comment: Thanks hugo! Sucks that there has to be so many problems with the toolkits and not enough documentation.

Comment: hey, I'm trying to catch any airtap. Why? Because I want to instantiate and place items while my spatial-map-process is running. But with this interfaces nothing happens. Do you know a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

There's an HTK to MRTK porting guide in the documentation: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/HTKToMRTKPortingGuide.html#interface-and-event-mappings

This contains an interface mapping table, which should help migrate prefabs and interfaces from HTK to MRTK v2.

As far as this specific case, `IMixedRealityPointerHandler` is indeed what you're looking for, if you need to know when a specific button (assigned to a specific pointer) has been clicked. If you're just looking to know when any button has been released, `IMixedRealityInputHandler` might be a better choice for you.